# How do I make this maze?

Tags: python, arrays

For my computing class I have to make a maze in a language of my choice I chose python. I tried but I couldn't work it out here are the instructions we were given:
This grid can be represented as a 2-D integer array:

```
DECLARE maze AS ARRAY OF ARRAY OF INTEGER INITIALLY []

SET maze TO [ [] ] * 9  # array with 9 elements, each an empty array
DECLARE maze AS ARRAY OF ARRAY OF INTEGER INITIALLY []

#This loop fills the 2-D array with the value -1.

SET maze TO [ [] ] * 9  # array with 9 elements, each an empty array
FOR counter FROM 0 TO 8 DO
    maze[ counter ] = [0] * -1

    # Update each element to be a 4-element array of -1s

END FOR
```

Once a 2D array, or array of arrays has been initialised, if you wanted to print out its contents as a table it could be done with this code:

```
FOR column FROM 0 TO 8 DO
    FOR row FROM 0 TO 3 DO
       SEND maze[column] [row] TO DISPLAY
    END FOR
    <print new line>
END FOR
```

This computational construct is often referred to as a nested loop.

We can now set the cells which need to contain a room number with a set of statements.

```
SET maze[0][1] TO 1 
SET maze[1][1] TO 2
SET maze[1][2] TO 4
SET maze[2][2] TO 5
SET maze[2][3] TO 1  .... etc.
```

Once this set of commands is complete, the result of moving from room to room can be coded using a procedure.

PROCEDURE ChangeRoom (INTEGER room, INTEGER direction)

```
DECLARE newRoom INITIALLY 0  
IF maze[room][direction] = -1  THEN
     SEND "you have hit a wall" TO DISPLAY
   ELSE
     SET newRoom TO maze[room][direction]
     SEND "You are now in room "& newRoom TO DISPLAY
 END IF
   SET room TO newRoom

END PROCEDURE
```

Comment: That's some form of Pascal/PLSQL/whatnot, not Python. Where's the problem?

Comment: I don't think they use any language in their examples it's a type of pseudocode as far as I know anyway they said to make that in python.

Comment: Copy-pasting your assignment here with "I tried but I couldn't work it out" isn't a question. Do your own homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import random
def init_maze():
    maze = [[]] * 9
    for counter in range(0, 9):
        maze[counter] = [-1] * 4
    return maze

def print_maze(maze):

    for column in range(0, 9):
        for row in range(0, 4):
            print maze[column][row],
        print ''

def set_cells(maze):
    for column in range(0, 9):
        for row in range(0, 4):
            maze[column][row] = random.randint(1,5)
    return maze

def change_room(room, direction):
    newRoom = 0
    if maze[room][direction] == -1:
        print "you have hit a wall"
    else:
        newRoom = maze[room][direction]
        print "You are now in room {0}".format(newRoom)
    room = newRoom

maze = init_maze()
print_maze(maze)
print 'Randomizing...'
maze = set_cells(maze)
print 'Done'
print_maze(maze)
```